# Word for excited, non-sexual heavy breathing

Tags: adjectives, emotions

I'm trying to describe a person taking deep excited breaths at seeing something they want with great desire.

*Panting* doesn't really fit because it's too fast and doesn't convey the wanting sensation.
Heavy breathing sounds a bit too sexually loaded.

I was thinking of *breathing haggardly* but I'm unsure if that would be a proper fit, because it calls to a scenario of someone who has been through hell and is out of breath trying to it.

What would be a good way to describe the type of breathing I'm trying to convey?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Panting can take place in an excited way:

> *Pant*[ing] *suggests rapid, convulsive breathing, as from violent exertion or
>   excitement*

[from Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/panting)

And Collins Dictionary gives 'eager' as one of its synonyms:

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/panting

In the same way thesaurus.com gives 'desire' as a synonym:

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/panting

Comment: Eager suits perfectly in what I'm trying to convey. It paints the correct picture in my mind.

Comment: Well there you go!  My pleasure.

Comment: "Panting doesn't really fit" said the questioner. lol

Comment: But s/he did not know it had my stated definition.  But yes, lol.